# Vaadin + Checkbox + Table + JPAContainer = Problems

Tags: java, jpa, checkbox, vaadin

I´m trying to create a table in Vaadin 7 that uses a JPAContainer as datasource. In one of the columns of this table i have a generated column to create a checkbox. I used the orientations of the documentation, and i have something similar to:

```
table.addGeneratedColumn(CHECKBOX_COLUMN, new Table.ColumnGenerator() {
      @Override
      public Object generateCell(final Table source, final Object itemId, Object columnId) {

        final CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox("", isItemIdSelected(source, itemId));
        checkBox.addValueChangeListener(new Property.ValueChangeListener() {
          @Override
          public void valueChange(Property.ValueChangeEvent valueChangeEvent) {

          }
});
```

After the users selects the rows he wants, he can press a save button.

At this moment, i was trying to loop throug the entire table (using table.getItemsIds() ) , check on each item the checkbox property, and if it is checked / selected, i add the item (the row / entity from the JPAContainer) to a collection that will be processed later. BUT i´m having severe performance problems in this loop (JPA is calling lazy attributes in the entity, generating many queries and making everything very slow). Well how can i setup a listener or something similar that will allow to have acess to the entire item (not just the checkbox property) each the user clicks (or unclicks) a checkbox? I´m using Vaadin. Hibernate 4/JPA and Spring.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    table.addGeneratedColumn(CHECKBOX_COLUMN, new Table.ColumnGenerator() {
        @Override
        public Object generateCell(final Table source, final Object itemId, Object columnId) {

            final CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
            checkBox.addValueChangeListener(new ValueChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {

                    /*
                     * do something with the itemId
                     */

                    //cast to Person entity if your table itemId is an entity object
                    Person person = (Person) itemId;
                    person.setActive(checkBox.getValue());
                }
            });

            return checkbox;
        }
    });
```

Comment: maybe this is what i need, i will test it soon, and if this work, i will accept your answer, thanks =)

Answer (score -1):

> how can i setup a listener or something similar that will allow to
>   have acess to the entire item (not just the checkbox property) each
>   the user clicks (or unclicks) a checkbox

what do you mean with "entire item" ? The Table itemId ? The entity object?

you can use the entity object as itemId in a vaadin table.

Comment: i mean the entity, that i´m adding to the table using table.addItem(entityInstance)

Comment: my difficult is how to acess the item / entity in the context that i related in the question

Comment: you can access the "itemId" object in the "valueChange" method